# Conditional formatting row referencing cells in another row

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm creating a list, and wish to link items in that list...
Here's a hypothetical setup to relay the basic issue:
column B is merely a list of successive numbers (1 through 1000)
column K receives a value of "O" or "C" depending on whether the issue is open or closed
column L receives a numerical value that references the value of column B in another row.

I want column L to link one row to another.

ex:
Value of B1 is "1" --->we'll call this "row 1"
Value of B2 is "2" --->we'll call this "row 2"

If L2 is "1", I want row 2 to be linked to row 1.
Then, if K1 is "O", I want no action to be applied to row 2.
However, if K1 is "C", I want row 2 to be highlighted.

Essentially, we're creating finish to start links for tasks.
Therefore, this should be able to have several rows with column L values all referencing the same column B value, so when that row is changed to closed/"C", those several other rows all become highlighted.

I've been digging for a while, so sincerely appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this...

Highlight the whole columns say B:L and make a New Rule for conditional formatting using the formula given below and set the format as per your choice.

```
=INDEX($K:$K,MATCH($L1,$B:$B,0))="C"
```

See if this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks--this is exactly what I was looking for... I ended up writing a two step solution to my original problem (I had an index formula on a hidden column that returned "o", "c", or "N/A" based upon the referenced row, then ran conditional formatting using that index formula in the present row), but I was able to simplify it to a single step with your solution. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it worked. Please take a moment to accept the solution to mark your question as Solved.